# Обработка простого json на java

Tags: json, java

Прошу помощи в разборке простого json на java:

```
{
  "names": [
    "name1",
    "name2"
  ]
}
```

Что-то ничего не выходит, не знаю как правильно подойти к массиву и объекту без имени. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал с помощью библиотеки Argo. Вопрос снят.

Answer (score 0):

В чем ты его хочешь распарсить? К примеру, заюзай Джексон.
[здесь](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: Я пробовал http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com, но моя дурная голова забыла как реализовать конструктор. Джексон что-то валится на new ObjectMapper();